# How do I draw an equilateral triangle with the sides of the midpoint connecting each other with LATEX? See below:)

Tags: math-mode

[image: The equilateral triangle with midpoint of the sides connecting to each other I am attempting to draw on Latex]

The equilateral triangle with midpoint of the sides connecting to each other I am attempting to draw on Latex.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276665/triangles-inside-triangle

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The solution of this question is a trivial case of the much more general solution [I made](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/615549/87876).

Answer (score 3):

Short code, without use of any library:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=cyan!30]
    (0,0)   -- coordinate (a) ++ 
    (+60:5) -- coordinate (b) ++ 
    (-60:5) -- coordinate (c) cycle;
\draw[red] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mytriangle{(90:1)--(210:1)--(-30:1)--cycle}
\draw[fill=yellow!50] \mytriangle;
\draw[yscale=-1,scale=.5] \mytriangle;      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: Long time ago, we made [a tutorial on drawing equilateral triangle with TikZ](https://www.facebook.com/groups/TikZandAsymptote/posts/487320585141304). There are several different way ^^ that illustrating TikZ's different commands: `plot coordinate`, `[turn]`, `++`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very difficult with tikz, in two lines.
A reading of the first part of the manual is enough to draw much more complex diagrams.

```
\documentclass[crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) coordinate(O) -- ++ (60:5) coordinate(A) --++ (-60:5) coordinate(B) -- cycle;
\draw[red] ($(O)!0.5!(A)$) coordinate(I1) -- ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) coordinate(I2) -- ($(B)!0.5!(O)$)-- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For this we need only the `calc` tikz library and not the `intersections` and the `positioning` ones